# Twilio send a voice message if user doesn't answer, in an outbound call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am new to using twilio. I am using twilio to make calls from browser to phone. In the browser side I am using twiml Device to connect to the call.

```
Twilio.Device.connect({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber, userId: id });
```

In the nodejs server side I am using this code.

```
import twilio from 'twilio';

const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse; 

let phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
let callerId = user.phoneNumber;
let twiml = new VoiceResponse();

let dial = twiml.dial({ callerId: callerId });
dial.number(phoneNumber);

res.send(twiml.toString());
```

If the user in the other end hasn't answered the call, I need to send a recording by pressing a button as a voicemail to that user.

```
<button>Send Voicemail</button>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using a combination of Twilio's Answering Machine Detection service and the `<Play>` TwiML verb.

[Here is a code sample](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection?code-sample=code-make-a-call-with-answering-machine-detection&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) of making an outbound call with answering machine detection.

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
  .create({
     machineDetection: 'Enable',
     url: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     to: '+1562300000',
     from: '+18180000000'
   })
 .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
 .done();
```

With AMD enabled on your call, Twilio will post the result of the call to the webhook you specify. That webhook will receive an `AnsweredBy` parameter that will indicate events like `machine_start` or `machine_end_beep`.

The controller that receives the webhook should respond by using the `<Play>` TwiML verb to "press" the correct button. [Here is a code sample](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play?code-sample=code-using-digits&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) of what that might look like (this code is untested):

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

app.post('/answering-machine-handler', function (req, res) {
  const response = new VoiceResponse();

  if (req.params.AnsweredBy === 'machine_start') {
    response.play({
        digits: 'wwww3'
    });
  } else {
    // Handle other cases here.
  }

  res.send(response);
})

console.log(response.toString());
```